# Unclosed Character Literal error

Tags: java, string, char

Got the error "Unclosed Character Literal" , using BlueJ, when writing:

```
class abc
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       String y;
       y = 'hello';
       System.out.println(y);
   }
}
```

But I can't figure out what is wrong.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Strings in Java need to be enclosed in double quotes. Use `"hello"`.

Comment: [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: Ok,so I got too many answer about correcting the answer,but why `String`s in " " and `char` in ' ' ?

Comment: and why not this `char y;y = 'hello';`

Comment: As I said in my answers, `char` can only take *one* character. It is a character by definition, and called a character for that exact reason.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Java, single quotes can only take one character, with escape if necessary. You need to use full quotation marks as follows for strings:

```
y = "hello";
```

You also used

```
System.out.println(g);
```

which I assume should be

```
System.out.println(y);
```

**Note:** When making `char` values (you'll likely use them later) you *need* single quotes. For example:

```
char foo='m';
```

Answer (score 9):

Java uses double quotes for `"String"` and single quotes for `'C'`haracters.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to give a small addition to the existing answers.
You get the same "Unclosed Character Literal error", if you give value to a char with incorrect unicode form.
Like when you write:

```
char HI = '\3072';
```

You have to use the correct form which is:

```
char HI = '\u3072';
```

Answer (score 2):

'' encloses single `char`, while "" encloses a `String`.

Change

```
y = 'hello';
```

-->

```
y = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

String y = "hello";

would work (note the double quotes).

char y = 'h';
 this will work for chars (note the single quotes)

but the type is the key: '' (single quotes) for one char, "" (double quotes) for string.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 primitive datatypes in Java.
[image]
`char` is one of them. When `compiler` sees a `char` datatype is defined. It allocates 1 Bytes of memory from JVM heap and expects a value after `=` symbol with two conditions.

1. value enclosed inside `'` (single quotes).
2. value to be single character long. It can be either a single character or valid code corresponding single character, which you can't type using English Keyboard.

In the same way, a datatype of String type should be enclosed with `"`(double quotes) and can have any length characters sequence.

In the given example you have mixed concepts of both `char` and `String` datatype. the compiler clearly saying:

> Unclosed Character Literal

Means, you started with `'` single quote, so compiler just expects a single character after opening `'` and then a closing `'`. Hence, the character literal is considered `unclosed` and you see the error.

So, either you use `char` data type and `'` single quotes to enclose single character.
Or use `String` datatype and `"` double quotes to enclose any length of character sequence.

So, correct way is:

```
String y = "hello";
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes symbol as I mention below
Your `y` data type is String, and it should double quotes symbol

```
class abc
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       String y;
       y = "hello";
       System.out.println(y);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Character only takes one value dude! like:
char y = 'h';
and maybe you typed like char y = 'hello'; or smthg. good luck. for the question asked above the answer is pretty simple u have to use DOUBLE QUOTES to give a string value. easy enough;)