# What is the mistake of char variable declaration?

Tags: java, variables, literals

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    //character variable declaration
    char a = '\c';//character variable declaration
    }
}
```

After compile this code it shows an error "Unclosed character literal".What is the wrong of this code?

Comment: What character are you trying to declare? Because `\c` is not a valid [escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: Why the backslash? A more descriptive error message I get is `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unclosed Character Literal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344312/unclosed-character-literal-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize with the character c, the use,

```
char a = 'c';
```

you don't need the escape character \ for initializing simple characters.

there are special cases where you may want to use \, for ex: \b,\r etc..
refer http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30241&seqNum=3

Answer (score 0):

> '\c' is not a escape sequence character and if you want to declare \c then declare as a String:

String a = "\c";