# Java char 'ß' in Gradle produces compiler error

Tags: java, gradle, char

I just played a bit around with chars and found this problem. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("aß".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
    System.out.println("ẞ");
    System.out.println("ẞ".equals("ß".toUpperCase()));
    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ß'));
    System.out.println('ß');
}
```

Running this results in this error:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Main.java:45: error: unclosed character literal
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ß'));
                                                 ^
Main.java:45: error: unclosed character literal
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ß'));
                                                    ^
Main.java:45: error: not a statement
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ß'));
                                                   ^
Main.java:46: error: unclosed character literal
        System.out.println('ß');
                           ^
Main.java:46: error: unclosed character literal
        System.out.println('ß');
                              ^
Main.java:46: error: not a statement
        System.out.println('ß');
                             ^
```

Why is it like this? I'm using Java 16 and Gradle 7.0. And how to workaround it? I tried to achieve a way, that `toUppercase()` of ß returns ẞ.

I just figured out something:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("aß".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
    System.out.println("ẞ");
    System.out.println("ẞ".equals("ß".toUpperCase()));
//  System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ß'));
//  System.out.println('ß');
    System.out.println("ß".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("ẞ".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("ß".toCharArray()[1]);
    System.out.println("ẞ".toCharArray()[0]);
}
```

This actually compiles:

```
Aß
ẞ
false
ß
ẞ
�
�
```

Even though IntelliJ warns me, that`"ß".toCharArray()[1]` will definitely throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`...

Its kinda strange, that "ß" and "ẞ" are each stored as two characters internal apparently. Is this intended? And if it is, why is it like this? Same problem with 'ä' 'ö' and 'ü' for example. The `toCharArray()`-Method returns a 2-Char-array for each letter. But according to the comments, this works on other PCs with the char literal. Am i missing something? Maybe System.out uses UTF-8 and the letters need 2 bytes to display?

I figured out something new. Since `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` returns windows-1252, I started thinking it's maybe that that causes the problem. So I added in the build.gradle this:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

Then I changed the Main:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("aß".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
    System.out.println("ẞ");
    System.out.println("ẞ".equals("ß".toUpperCase()));
    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ß'));
    System.out.println('ß');
    System.out.println("ß".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("ẞ".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("ß".toCharArray()[1]);
    System.out.println("ẞ".toCharArray()[0]);
```

Output is:

```
windows-1252
ASS
ẞ
false
ß
ß
ß
ẞ
```

So apparently that works at compiletime (after that output I get an AIOOB), however that didn't change the file.encoding. I would need to add the JVM.Arg every time I start. That doesn't sound how it should work. Without the Arg I need the second line, else the output is still trash.
So if I add in the build.gradle the 2 compile encodings and the JVM-Arg, it compiles at least like it should.

But the original problem was, I wanted a method to change ß to ẞ without my own method, but I think that won't work.

So it's just a Windows-1252 problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unclosed Character Literal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344312/unclosed-character-literal-error)

Comment: No, since i just have a Single letter inside the '' and the Error still comes up. Dont know why im getting downvoted

Comment: Actually I can compile your code using Java 11 and Gradle 6.7 and I would guess that I will not have different results using Java 16.

Comment: If thats the case, what else is then the Problem? U see above all code and the Error. Gradle -debug doesnt give any more helpful Information.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue on Java 11 or 16.  As even your directory name isn't displaying properly, what version of Java 16 are you using and what is your locale setting on your machine?

Comment: Im using OpenJDK 16: https://jdk.java.net/16/ and Windows with German Locale (The Beta UTF-8 Option is not checked).. Gradle 7.0: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip
The non-displaying Character in the Directory is an 'ö'. But thats just an Intellij-Problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Replaced them with The output

Comment: Your error shows that this is on a line that doesn't exist in your code.  Can you post an example that is reproducible?

Comment: What line is missing? Thats all Code from the Main-Method. In it there isnt more. The Error refernces to the last 2 Lines

Comment: The error is on like 45 and you posted 7 lines.  In your real code what are the 3 lines above line 45?

Comment: System.out.println("aß".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
    System.out.println("ẞ");
    System.out.println("ẞ".equals("ß".toUpperCase()));
This 3. above is just the main declaration. There is a big Comment on top of the file, if thats what confuses u. There is no other code

Comment: @Schesam What is the encoding of the file? Is it UTF16 by any chance? Best check with a hex editor if all ASCII characters are 1 byte and the umlauts are 2 bytes or more (and are actually the correct byte values).

Comment: @Schesam correct byte values for _utf-8_ would be 0xc39f for 'ß' and 0xe1ba9e for 'ẞ'. I just tried in a Java 11 (11.0.11) `jshell` and `"ẞ".toCharArray()[1]` throws an AIOOBEx

Comment: I triple checked it: The encoding of the Main.java is UTF-8 NO BOM.
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding")); returns windows.1252 and if i set UTF-8 to Sysout, then the output is just trash.

Comment: The problem is probably that your sources are saved as UTF-8 (ß is two bytes: 0xC3 0x9F, and ẞ is 3 bytes: 0xE1 0xBA 0x9E), but the default character set used by `javac` **on your system** is probably windows-1252 (ß 0xDF, ẞ does not exist). So by setting the character set in Gradle, the problem should be solved; this is only a compiletime problem, though printing characters might add an extra problem depending on the console)